# Usage of Activator.CreateInstance()

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, activator

What is actually the difference between the below two code snippets?

```
Object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(StringBuilder));

StringBuilder sb = (StringBuilder) o;
```

and

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Answer (score 4):

From a practical point of view. There is no difference.

However, from a technical point of view. The first will incur a substantial performance penalty.

First, from the `Activator.CreateInstance`, since this is a Reflection call.

Then another performance hit when you cast `object` to `StringBuilder`.

From a design point of view however. `Activator.CreateInstance` takes `Type` as a parameter...

This means you can do the following...

```
public IStringBuilder ActivateStringBuilder(Type builderType)
{
     return (IStringBuilder) Activator.CreateInstance(builderType);
}
```

Ignoring that there is no such thing as `IStringBuilder` the above code allows you to, at runtime, change the behavior of the code, by passing in different `Type`s that implement `IStringBuilder`.

This is the basis for Dependency Injection (although, we tend to use much more complicated mechanisms to get around the performance issues I pointed out).

Comment: Thankyou for pointing out that DI part. I was getting trouble in understanding code at my first job.